# How to remote debug a NodeJS app deployed on DigitalOcean App Platform?

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, digital-ocean, remote-debugging, digital-ocean-apps

I have a deployed a NodeJS app on Digitalocean's app platform and its exposed on `myserver.ondigitalocean.app`

My intention is to connect it with VSCode on my computer and run the debugger remotely.

So far I've managed to tell App Platform to start the app using `node --inspect myserver.js`.

NodeJS starts in inspect mode giving me a url + UUID (similar to `ws://127.0.0.1:9229/unique-UUID-f63b0f33d55e` to connect my debugger.

As you can see, the inspector's URL is pointing to `localhost` which is fine, but I'm having issues trying to connect it to my VSCode locally.

In theory all I should do is configure my VSCode `launch.json` to point to the public URL and add the UUID provided by the inspector (essentially this `ws://myserver.ondigitalocean.app/unique-UUID-f63b0f33d55e`) but it's not working (I haven't found official DigitalOcean documentation on how to achieve this so I'm assuming based on NodeJS's documentation)

Checking the official [NodeJS remote debugging documentation](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/debugging-getting-started/#enabling-remote-debugging-scenarios), it seems that I could do a `SSH tunnel` to the server and that way I would be able to use VSCode debugger as "local" while it is really hitting the remote server through the tunnel. Now, the problem with this approach is that [DigitalOcean App Platform doesn't allow SSH access](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/how-to-enable-ssh-on-app-platform).

This is how my `launch.json` file looks like, perhaps I'm missing something.

```
{
   "type": "pwa-node",
   "request": "attach",
   "name": "Attach to remote",
   "address": "ws://myserver.ondigitalocean.app:9229/unique-UUID-f63b0f33d55e",
   "port": 9229
}
```

Maybe App Platform doesn't expose port 9229 or WS? Or maybe I'm configuring the launch file in the wrong way.

Thanks for the help!